# Mathematics involved in algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, math, analytics

Please help me in following question

```
which function grows faster?
n^log n or n*log n
```

I have encountered this question during algorithm analysis...

Answer (score 1):

n^log(n) will grows faster because multiplication of two numbers is less than number raised to power of other number. I know, here some values of n^log(n) will be less but in general n^log(n) will always be greater than n*log(n).